# Convert day and hour in user time zone

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, postgresql, timezone

I want to convert the group date (day + hour) to user time zone to show the list, i don't want update the db. I have several groups and this code is veeeeery slow.

```
# GROUP.RB
# day  -> Date
# hour -> Time
# wday -> Integer
.
.
groups.each do |g|
    new_day = g.in_gmt_day(user_time_zone) # <-- Concat group.day with group.hour and convert the result day with the user time zone.
    g.wday = new_day.wday
    g.hour = new_day
end
.
.
```

Any one can help me?

Thanks.

Comment: Is there any chance you can change your storage so you store a single `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE` field like `2012-01-01 11:00:00 UTC` (for date 2012-01-01, hour 11) ? It'll make everything MUCH easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let Postgres do this for you:

```
SELECT (day + hour) AT TIME ZONE '<source tz>' AT TIME ZONE 'localtime'
FROM   groups;
```

This does

1. create a `timestamp [without time zone]` out of the two columns of data types `date` and `time` (assuming here, the question is vague about the exact data types):

   ```
   day + hour
   ```
2. Set this timestamp at the time zone of the source, let's use 'Europe/London' as example. Results in a `timestamp with time zone` (or `timestamptz` for short):

   ```
   (day + hour) AT TIME ZONE 'Europe/London'
   ```
3. Show the equivalent local `timestamp [without time zone]`:

   ```
   (day + hour) AT TIME ZONE 'Europe/London' AT TIME ZONE 'localtime'
   ```

From here you can do anything with the value, like split up in day and time again, or format it any way you like with `to_char()`:

```
WITH x AS (
   SELECT (day + hour) AT TIME ZONE 'Europe/London' AT TIME ZONE 'localtime' AS ts
   FROM   groups
   )
SELECT ts::date AS day, ts::time AS hour, to_char(ts, 'HH24') AS h24
FROM   x;
```